# ¿Como puedo hacer, con CSS, que desaparezca una imagen cuando le quitas el cursor de encima?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, web

Estoy haciendo un menú de navegación. Mi idea es que cuando haces Focus en un elemento del menú, al desplegarse (pero dentro del mismo menú), aparezca una foto junto al texto, y que cuando apartes el ratón, la imagen desaparezca. LA parte de poner la imagen en el menú está controlada, pero ¿cómo hago que se vaya?. Thanks :)

Comment: Para que te puedan ayudar en este sitio tenes que poner el codigo que intentaste, si pedis que te resuelvan un problema desde cero te van a llenar la pregunta de puntos negativos.

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Ten en cuenta que [es.so] no es un sitio de tutoriales. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: [`hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) es lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es ocultar una imagen cuando pases el ratón encima, tienes que usar el efecto `hover`, por ejemplo, insertamos una imagen:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZnpyoVz.jpeg" alt="" class="main">
</div>
```

y en el css iría así:

```
.main{
  width: 250px;
}

.main:hover{
  display: none;
}
```

Puedes ver más a detalle en este [proyecto](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/RwMyGXx), saludos.